# Spread Amount Over Months Between Two Dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data that looks like this

| Name | Amount | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | $1 | 9/1/22 | 10/31/22 |
| B | $3 | 10/15/22 | 12/2/22 |
| C | $4 | 9/18/22 | 9/30/22 |

I would like to spread the amount over the number of months in between both and take the final aggregate. So I would like the result to look like the following

| Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $4.5 | $1.5 | $1 | $1 |

**A**: $1 would be spread over September and October ($0.5 each)

**B**: $3 would be spread over 3 months October, November & December ($1 each) (Yes, December counts as a full month, should be blind to the day)

**C**: $4 Would all land in September

---

**Bonus 1**:
How can I aggregate by Quarter?

**Bonus 2**: Is there a way in which I can weight the spread even further. So for example: have the value spread over the days and then aggregated. So take customer B for example: we would spread the $3 over (47 days) - 15 days in October, 30 days in November & 2 days for December. That would look like

| Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $3x(15/47) | $3x(30/47) | $3(2/47) |

Answer (score 1):

This solution will use a package called [`staircase`](https://www.staircase.dev) which is part of the [`pandas` ecosystem](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/ecosystem.html#staircase) and designed to work with (mathematical) step functions.  Any time your data is dealing with "starts" and "ends" you can ask yourself whether your data is representing step functions.

**setup**

Create the dataframe (Name column seems irrelevant) and make sure dates are `pandas.Timestamp`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Amount":[1,3,4],
        "Start":["2022-09-01", "2022-10-15", "2022-09-18"],
        "End":["2022-10-31", "2022-12-02", "2022-09-30"],
    }
)
df[["Start", "End"]] = df[["Start", "End"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

**solution**

We'll go straight to "Bonus 2".

Create a step function using the `staircase.Stairs` object - it represents a step function and is to `staircase` what `pandas.Series` is to `pandas`.

```
import staircase as sc
sf = sc.Stairs(frame=df, start="Start", end="End", value="Amount")
```

`sf` will increase at points given by the "Start" column, and decrease at points given by the "End" column.  The increase/decrease will be given by the Amount column.

You can even plot your step function to look at it

```
sf.plot()
```

[image]

Now create "cuts" for your monthly buckets

```
months = pd.period_range("2022-09", "2022-12", freq="M")
cuts = months.union([months[-1]+1]).start_time
```

`cuts` is a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` and looks like this

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01',
            '2023-01-01'],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Then slice the step function up by this bucket and use the `mean` function, which will give the average value of the step function in each bucket - this is "spreading" it out

```
 sf.slice(cuts).mean()
```

The result is a `pandas.Series` indexed by your monthly intervals

```
[2022-09-01, 2022-10-01)    2.600000
[2022-10-01, 2022-11-01)    2.612903
[2022-11-01, 2022-12-01)    3.000000
[2022-12-01, 2023-01-01)    0.096774
dtype: float64
```

If you want to aggregate by quarter, then define your cuts to be the points which define quarters - the above approach is very flexible.

note: I am the creator of staircase, and happy to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems very interesting. The issue is I am using this on company servers and unfortunately cannot install your package.

Comment: Your result doesn't seem correct - there is a $0 result for September when it should be at least $4

Comment: @Nick good pickup, I've made the edit, the previous results were just for "B" - I forgot to change it back.  I don't agree with September being at least $4 though.

Comment: @Riley the last line in OPs data has $4 for the period Sep 18- Sep 30, so September is definitely at least $4

Comment: @nick yes thats $4 over 13 days which then gets spread across 30

Comment: @Riley the way OP describes the operation is that September would get `$4*(12/12) = $4` for that value.

Comment: @nick I think you're right :|